A new command for hanging indentation works in LaTeX but not in Pandoc for some reason
LaTeX
This is my minimum working environment for LaTeX:
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\hangingindent}{\medskip\par\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=1}

\title{Detraxit consequat mnesarchum}
\author{Dolor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Detraxit consequat mnesarchum in per, labores conclusionemque sea te. Duo convenire persecuti mnesarchum ne, sea corpora consequuntur ad. Eros option vituperatoribus an nec, meis debet id eum. Dico iisque inimicus eu ius. Movet democritum elaboraret vel ei, in nulla aperiri per.

\hangingindent Te, Accumsan. Sit wisi graeci saperet cu. Ex nihil probatus pericula eam. Per te dicta altera posidonium. Cu has iisque appetere gloriatur, quas maiorum accommodare usu in. Cu facer nominati quaerendum eum.


\smallskip

Ut nam insolens urbanitas maiestatis, feugiat dignissim intellegam et ius. Ne salutandi efficiantur cum, ex usu alii ipsum maiorum. Eos iriure dolorum in. Id vel appareat platonem.
    
\end{document}

It produces the following output as (mostly) desired:

(I'd like to integrate the smallskip after the paragraph into the command but haven't figured it out, but this isn't my question right now.)
Pandoc markdown
The following is my minimum working environment for pandoc in trying to use the same newcommand but for markdown to PDF conversion.
---
title: Detraxit consequat mnesarchum
author: Dolor
documentclass: article
header-includes: \newcommand{\hangingindent}{\medskip\par\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=1}
---



Detraxit consequat mnesarchum in per, labores conclusionemque sea te. Duo convenire persecuti mnesarchum ne, sea corpora consequuntur ad. Eros option vituperatoribus an nec, meis debet id eum. Dico iisque inimicus eu ius. Movet democritum elaboraret vel ei, in nulla aperiri per.

\hangingindent Te, Accumsan. Sit wisi graeci saperet cu. Ex nihil probatus pericula eam. Per te dicta altera posidonium. Cu has iisque appetere gloriatur, quas maiorum accommodare usu in. Cu facer nominati quaerendum eum.

\smallskip

Ut nam insolens urbanitas maiestatis, feugiat dignissim intellegam et ius. Ne salutandi efficiantur cum, ex usu alii ipsum maiorum. Eos iriure dolorum in. Id vel appareat platonem.


As you can see, the output is not produced as expected. The hanging indentation works as desired on LaTeX but not on Pandoc.
I would like to ask how to get this to work correctly on pandoc?

I just used a very basic pandoc test.md -t pdf -f markdown -o test.pdf --verbose  I could convert markdown to LaTeX then PDF, I suppose.

ignoring pandoc for now, test your definition with \hangingindent  10 years ago, something...

Not that it apparently matters, but I would move \noindent after \hangafter=1.  That way \hangindent etc. are defined in vmode, whereas \noindent starts hmode.

Because of how Pandoc works, the generated TeX code of your markdown code is (generated using pandoc test.md -t latex -o test.tex):
Detraxit consequat mnesarchum in per, labores conclusionemque sea te. Duo convenire persecuti mnesarchum ne, sea corpora consequuntur ad. Eros option vituperatoribus an nec, meis debet id eum. Dico iisque inimicus eu ius. Movet democritum elaboraret vel ei, in nulla aperiri per.

\medskip
Te, Accumsan. Sit wisi graeci saperet cu. Ex nihil probatus pericula eam. Per te dicta altera posidonium. Cu has iisque appetere gloriatur, quas maiorum accommodare usu in. Cu facer nominati quaerendum eum.

\smallskip
Ut nam insolens urbanitas maiestatis, feugiat dignissim intellegam et ius. Ne salutandi efficiantur cum, ex usu alii ipsum maiorum. Eos iriure dolorum in. Id vel appareat platonem.

And for this code, the PDF result you've shown in your question is correct. So this question is not really a LaTeX question but a question on how to add raw LaTeX code to Pandoc and how Pandoc works in such a case. (And therefore IMHO is off-topic here, but nevertheless I'll try a suggestion of an answer.)
After reading section "6.11 Write raw LaTeX code" in the Pandoc documentation you may think, that the correct solution would be to use:
```{=latex}
\hangingindent
```
Te, Accumsan. Sit wisi graeci saperet cu. Ex nihil probatus pericula eam. Per te dicta altera posidonium. Cu has iisque appetere gloriatur, quas maiorum accommodare usu in. Cu facer nominati quaerendum eum.

But this would result in
\hangingindent

Te, Accumsan. Sit wisi graeci saperet cu. Ex nihil probatus pericula eam. Per te dicta altera posidonium. Cu has iisque appetere gloriatur, quas maiorum accommodare usu in. Cu facer nominati quaerendum eum.

So you would need to use
```{=latex}
\hangingindent
Te, Accumsan. Sit wisi graeci saperet cu. Ex nihil probatus pericula eam. Per te dicta altera posidonium. Cu has iisque appetere gloriatur, quas maiorum accommodare usu in. Cu facer nominati quaerendum eum.
```

instead. Another suggestion would be to use an environment:
---
title: Detraxit consequat mnesarchum
author: Dolor
documentclass: article
header-includes: \newenvironment{hangingindent}{\medskip\par\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=1}{\par\smallskip}
---



Detraxit consequat mnesarchum in per, labores conclusionemque sea te. Duo convenire persecuti mnesarchum ne, sea corpora consequuntur ad. Eros option vituperatoribus an nec, meis debet id eum. Dico iisque inimicus eu ius. Movet democritum elaboraret vel ei, in nulla aperiri per.

\begin{hangingindent}
Te, Accumsan. Sit wisi graeci saperet cu. Ex nihil probatus pericula eam. Per te dicta altera posidonium. Cu has iisque appetere gloriatur, quas maiorum accommodare usu in. Cu facer nominati quaerendum eum.
\end{hangingindent}

Ut nam insolens urbanitas maiestatis, feugiat dignissim intellegam et ius. Ne salutandi efficiantur cum, ex usu alii ipsum maiorum. Eos iriure dolorum in. Id vel appareat platonem.

This results in LaTeX code:
Detraxit consequat mnesarchum in per, labores conclusionemque sea te.
Duo convenire persecuti mnesarchum ne, sea corpora consequuntur ad. Eros
option vituperatoribus an nec, meis debet id eum. Dico iisque inimicus
eu ius. Movet democritum elaboraret vel ei, in nulla aperiri per.

\bgroup \medskip\par\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=1
Te, Accumsan. Sit wisi graeci saperet cu. Ex nihil probatus pericula eam. Per te dicta altera posidonium. Cu has iisque appetere gloriatur, quas maiorum accommodare usu in. Cu facer nominati quaerendum eum.
\smallskip\egroup

Ut nam insolens urbanitas maiestatis, feugiat dignissim intellegam et
ius. Ne salutandi efficiantur cum, ex usu alii ipsum maiorum. Eos iriure
dolorum in. Id vel appareat platonem.

and in the PDF output:

One advantage of this solution is, that the end of the hanging paragraph is also defined in the preamble. So if you decide to change all the \smallskip to, e.g., \bigskip you can do this in the preamble.
One final note: I don't like such mixtures of markdown and LaTeX, because the source file cannot be used as a standalone markdown file any longer, it depends too much on using LaTeX. So why not writing in LaTeX? With package markdown you could still use some markdown parts, if you are faster in typing markdown.

Wow this works so well. Thanks for this environment. I did try an environment solution first, but after some frustration, I thought newenvironments weren't possible in pandoc, though it did work on LaTeX

Solution 1:
`\hangingindent`{=latex} Te, Accumsan. 

This prohibits pandoc from interpreting or expanding the macro. This is needed because pandoc fails to read anything after a \par in a macro definition for some odd reason. A macro that type  "foo\par baz" is expanded just to "foo" even using +raw_tex.
Solution 2:
Do not use \par. It does nothing here.
Solution 3:
Instead of markdown or Rmarkdown, use Quarto markdown. For this format your  YAML header produces an error, but with this simple modification:
header-includes:
- \newcommand ... (etcetera)

Or better (new YAML syntax):
include-in-header:
- text: \newcommand ... (etcetera)

Then, the document (with the .qmd extension) can be rendered as latex or pdf and the macro will not be changed in the text, so it will work as expected for latex and pdf versions. Interestingly, the embedded Pandoc within Quarto makes the same jokes that Pandoc alone, whereas the preview or render options preserve the macro command, e.g:
quarto pandoc -f markdown -t latex foo.qmd # bad result

quarto render  foo.qmd --to latex  # good result

